# jna calls the so file in the jar package

Tags: java, linux, jna

I will be using JNA to load multiple ".so" files in a Spring Boot project. These ".so" files also need to access ".csv" files in the same directory. I've placed them in a folder under the "resources" directory. However, when I package the project into a JAR file, I receive an error message saying "Error: failed to open file." I'd like to inquire whether the ".so" and ".csv" files can only be placed outside the JAR package. If they are inside the JAR package, how should I go about accessing them?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de1Yf.jpg)

I'm not sure if it's due to my technical limitations or if ".so" files are generally meant to be loaded externally.

Comment: Is it .so or .csv? Your question is confusing. Is this a JNA problem or a Java classpath problem? Your question is confusing.  Some code showing specifically what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: You can click on the image link above to view the specific code. I need to call the ".so" file, which in turn requires accessing a ".csv" file. Both of these files are located in the "resources" directory. I'm unsure about the exact location where I might have made a mistake in specifying the paths, leading to the "Error: failed to open file" message.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  From a quick glance it looks like your path begins with a slash which means file system absolute; when extracting from a jar if you want it found on class path you should not have that leading slash.

Comment: Take a look at this workaround in case you want to put stuff inside `JAR` file and then access it from the native code: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo035